# Detect nullable type

Tags: c#, nullable

Is it possible to detect a Nullable type (cast into an object) when it is null?

Since `Nullable<T>` is really a struct I think it should be possible.

```
double? d = null;
var s = GetValue(d); //I want this to return "0" rather than ""

public string GetValue(object o)
{
    if(o is double? && !((double?)o).HasValue) //Not working with null
       return "0";
    if(o == null)
       return "";
    return o.ToString();
}
```

Comment: If a routine which accepts a parameter of type 'object' is passed a variable of type `Nullable<double>`, then the routine will either receive a null object reference (if the variable was null), or a reference to a `System.Double` (if the variable was not null).  It will not box an instance of `Nullable<System.Double>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597(v=vs.80).aspx

> Objects based on nullable types are only boxed if the object is
>   non-null. If HasValue is false, then, instead of boxing, the object
>   reference is simply assigned to null.

and

> If the object is non-null -- if HasValue is true -- then boxing takes
>   place, but only the underlying type that the nullable object is based
>   upon is boxed.

So you either have a `double` or a `null`.

```
public string GetValue(object o)
{
    if(o == null) // will catch double? set to null
       return "";

    if(o is double) // will catch double? with a value
       return "0";

    return o.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So the answer is No, it is not possible unfortunately. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Magnus But remember what Skeet told you. There is a way, but not through boxing. In the end all depends on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

You have the method GetValueOrDefault for every Nullable type, isn't it enough ?

Comment: Since I take it `object` in my function I would need to cast it to Nullable<T> to be able to use that function. (as in my example)

Comment: You don't need your function with this method, you can do GetDateOrDefault().ToString()

Comment: Yeh, but this is a generic formatting function for all types. And I want to be able to detect all Nullable numeric types that are null and return "0" instead.

Comment: all "nullable type" are not numeric (ie GUID)

Comment: Not, but those are the only ones i'm interested in (for example double? as in the example)

Answer (score 3):

Your method currently takes `object`, which means the nullable value will be boxed... and will no longer be a nullable value. The value of `o` will *either* be a boxed value of the non-nullable type, or a null reference.

If at all possible, change your method to be generic:

```
public string GetValue<T>(T value)
{
    // Within here, value will still be a Nullable<X> for whatever type X
    // is appropriate. You can check this with Nullable.GetUnderlyingType
}
```

Comment: Just to make this more clear, this means that there's no difference between a boxed nullable type that is null, and a null reference, in the memory. So there's no way to tell from within the method.

Comment: @Iravanchi: I'd put it more strongly than that: there's no such thing as a boxed nullable type *at all*. The result of boxing a nullable type value is *either* a boxed non-nullable type, or a null reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the object is boxed before it reaches the GetValue function, so I cant use your generic example.

Comment: @Magnus: In that case there is no way of detecting the difference between a value which was originally a null `double?` and a value which was a normal null reference.

Answer (score 0):

If `o` is `null` then `o is double?` will be false. No matter the value of your input parameter `double? d`

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, if you are trying to detect if ANY object is nullable, this can be written fairly easily.

try this...

```
public static bool IsNullable(dynamic value)
{
    try
    {
        value = null;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Simple!

Comment: Even if one calls `IsNullable(5)`, the `value = null` statement will overwrite a storage location of type `object`, rather than one of type `int`.

Comment: You are correct. In hindsight I had not double-checked this. Ideally the most elegant solution (at least in .net) should check to see if the object is a class or struct, and determine the "nullability" of the object. I believe my understanding is correct that structs cannot be null since they are value types which exist on the stack, and classes are reference types which exist on the heap, and therefore are references as opposed to absolute values. I am going to go away and investigate further.

Comment: There are three kinds of things in .net that are convertible to `Object`: Nullable value types, non-nullable value types, and objects.  Note that value types are not objects, even though every non-nullable value type has an associated "boxed" object type to which it is implicitly convertible, and every non-null nullable value type is implicitly convertible to the object type associated with its non-nullable equivalent.  C# defines "derive" in such a way that value types "derive" from `Object`, but they don't do so in the sense that other inherited class types define from their bases.

Comment: It is useful to define inheritance in such a way that if `X` is inherits from `Y`, copying a variable `xx` of type `X` to a variable `yy` of type `Y` will make `yy` refer to the same object instance as `xx`, so `Object.ReferenceEquals(xx,yy)` will be true.  Defining "interitance" in such a way that the above behavior always applies, and saying unboxed value types don't inherit from `Object` but boxed ones do, is more helpful IMHO than saying that all value types derive from `Object`, but some inheritance relations don't behave like normal ones.

Comment: Parting note: the distinction between non-nullable value types, nullable value types, and objects, is applicable to <i>storage locations</i> (variables, parameters, fields, or array slots) and not instances.  A storage location of one of those kinds will always hold things of that kind or (for the latter two kinds) `null`.  Generic type parameters can refer to any of those kinds of things, however.  Note also that storage locations of interface types are always object references, but generic types which are constrained to interfaces may be value types or class types.

Comment: I'm going back to school!...this is rather a lot to get my head round in one go